# Noether's theorem confusion about neglection terms

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

The following question is truly about lagrangian and actions that you might think is a physics question, but it's actually not, so bear with me.

Assume you have an action: 
$S[q] = \int L(q, \dot q, t)$ (i.e $q$ is a function of time). (1) 
 Then you do a transformation on $q(t)$ such as $\sigma(q(t), a)$ where $a$ is infinetisemal and this results in:  $S[\sigma(q(t), a)] = \int L'(\sigma(q,a), \frac{d}{dt}\sigma(q,a), t)dt$. (2)

Assume that when you do such transformation, $S[q]$ and $S[\sigma(q(t), a)]$ end up in a difference by total time derivative of some function(i.e $\frac{d}{dt}\Lambda(q,t)$.

---

Now here is what the [article](https://jhwilson.com/blog/2022/Noether-classical/) does.

we can expand (2) in taylor series: 
 $S[\sigma(q(t), a)] = \int dt(L(q, \dot q, t) + a\left[\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\right]_{a=0} + a^2\left[\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\right]_{a=0} + ...)$ 
 $S[\sigma(q(t), a)] - S[q] = \int dt(a\left[\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\right]_{a=0} + a^2\left[\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\right]_{a=0} + ...)$ 
 left side is our assumption that actions ended up differed by total time derivative, so: 
 $\int \frac{d}{dt}\Lambda(q,t) = \int dt(a\left[\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\right]_{a=0} + a^2\left[\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\right]_{a=0} + ...)$

---

and Now the magic happens: we neglect higher orders and say: $\int \frac{d}{dt}\Lambda(q,t) = \int dt(a\left[\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\right]_{a=0})$ (3)

**Question:**

Can you explain why this is justified ? It seems to me that (3) is not a strict equality, but approximation($\approx$) - you might say that since $a$ is infinetisemal, higher orders would be super small and can be neglected, but I don't get sure in that statement, because from (3), we derive conservation law, and if (3) is approximation, then how can conservation law derivation be legit ?

In other words, if $a = b + c + ...$, can we say $a=b$ if $c$ is infinetisemally small compared to $b$ and is this justified all the time ? if yes, how can this be justified in the action example I provided where from it, conservation law is derived ?

I am not so keen on this exact example and we can simplify explanation by using normal functions, I just need to understand this concept of neglection, but from mathematical viewpoint and physics viewpoint(as seen from mathematics as well).

Comment: Maybe this helps: we have *approximately* $f(x) \approx f(0) + f'(0)x$, but *precisely* $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}$. Physicists often make approximations to first order and then assert that they constitute equalities. Making the argument formal is usually as simple as setting up the difference quotient and passing a limit. But maybe you can see why the former is often more straightforward and enlightening than the latter, hence the physicist's preference.

Comment: I understand this but unfortunately, doesn't help with my question. Thank you though

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why it doesn't help. If you form the difference quotient you'll see that only the linear term survives in the limit, which is exactly what you want. Maybe you also want to know that Noether's theorem is really a theorem on vector fields not flows, so that we really only do care what happens in the limit, not what happens after some small time later.

Comment: can you tell why only linear term survives in the limit and not for example quadratic term ? @CharlesHudgins

Comment: Or rather the result applies to the flow of a vector field, but we only need the data of a vector field for the theorem, not a flow.

Comment: divide by a on both sides. The terms that don't have an a after this division are what survive in the limit.

Comment: In $\int \frac{d}{dt}\Lambda(q,t) = \int dt[a\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\Bigr|_{a=0} + a^2\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\Bigr|_{a=0} + ...]$, if you divide both sides by $a$, you get: $\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{d}{dt}\Lambda(q,t) = \int dt[\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\Bigr|_{a=0} + a\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\Bigr|_{a=0} + ...]$. Note that $a=0$ evaluation is not for powers of $a$, it's only for derivatives. Is this considered in your reply ?

Comment: I see the confusion. Your $\Lambda$ is an object that exists (in any well defined way) only after the limit $a \to 0$ has been passed. So we have something post-limit on the left and pre-limit on the right. An unfortunate but perhaps regrettably standard abuse of notation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150382/discussion-between-giorgi-and-charles-hudgins).

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I started the chat, but if you can't now, my comment is that you might be confusing the fact that $a=0$ evaluation happens for both powers and derivative, while it's not. I should have stated it such as: $\int dt \frac{d}{dt}\Lambda(q,t) = \int dt(a\left[\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\right]_{a=0} + a^2\left[\frac{\partial L'}{\partial a}\right]_{a=0} + ...)$

Comment: We use $dW^2=dt$ and $dWdt=dt^2=0$, for example, in stochastic calculus to describe Brownian motion. This is to match our notion that an infinitesimal change in $W$ must still have a nonzero variance $E[dW^2]-E[dW]^2$. I imagine that in your problem the intention is to use the infinitesimal $a$ precisely in this way so that $adt\neq 0$ while $a^ndt=0$ for all higher powers, simply by definition.

Comment: The left hand side, the infinitesimal change in the action, looks a lot like Brownian motion actually. I think the idea is that $a\sim dS/dt$, so that $a^2dt=dS^2/dt=0$ for reasons similar to why $dWdt=0$. Is there some physical reason maybe why $dS/dt$ should be infinitesimally small, such as $S$ is near a local minimum or maximum in the integral?

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont know brownian motion and really dont want to get into this. Would appreciate the explanation specific on my problem. Thanks though @Barri

Answer (score 0):

Reading your article, the authors claim between (7) and (8) that "To extremize the action, we cannot have a term proportional to $\alpha(t)$ which means the term multiplying it is zero". They are not claiming that all of the higher-order terms are also zero. They are only claiming that, at an extrema (local min or max), the term corresponding to the first derivative $$\frac{d}{dt}\left[ \Lambda - \left( \left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial \alpha} \right|_{\alpha=0} \right) \right]$$ must be zero. You mischaracterized the article's claim in your question (3).

Comment: I actually think the statement applies to all curves $q(t)$, not just extremals. For example, a Lagrangian which has rotational symmetry has action preserved under a rotation for any curve, not just for the ones which have stationary action.

Comment: No, that's not right ! Author first describes transformation by a value(infinetisemal) in the first half, then discusses $a(t)$ transformation. In the first half, there's no notion why $a(t)$ term must be 0 as there's no $a(t)$ mentioned. So, unfortunately, no, that's not the case :)

Comment: I think the authors of the article would agree with you @podiki. They write after (5) "We will use it for the extremal paths that minimize the action in order to derive Noether’s theorem." I'm sure you could also use it for non-extremal paths as you suggest.

Comment: Hopefully the statement after (5) addresses @Giorgi's comment as well, as to why the authors don't mention the first-order term needing to be zero in any prior steps

Comment: To repeat, it's important to first discuss transformation by $a$ and then by $a(t)$. This is very important in this theorem, so whatever author says in the first half is true on its own without even any extremum notion or whatever !

Comment: if you can't first show why $\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}$ is total derivative(which can only be done by the first half on its own), then you can't really even continue proving it in the next half.

Comment: I'm not here to defend what the authors are doing. They explain in the second paragraph after (5), "In this way, we will obtain a term proportional to $\alpha(t)$ and it must be zero on the paths that minimize the action". I simply hoped to clarify that they were not trying to claim that all higher-order terms were zero :)

Comment: Yes, I understand and thank you for trying. All I said is that's not the case

Comment: You are welcome, I always love to engage in new problems. It appears to me that, a symmetry is a symmetry, and a conservation law is a conservation law, and Noether's theorem is just that every symmetry induces a conservation law. Like in @podiki's example, $L$ with rotational symmetry preserves the action for any curve. But is the corresponding $Q$ conserved on every curve? Does Noether's theorem actually claim this, or does it only claim that $Q$ is conserved for the rotational symmetry $\sigma$ on curves that minimize the action?